# Strict inequalities in LP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

How should we deal with strict inequalities in a linear programming problem? For example:

inequalities such as $ax< b$;

Comment: Add a tolerance, $\epsilon>0$ and try solving with $ax \leq b-\epsilon$.

Comment: @copper.hat Does tha apply to answer below?

Comment: @BCLC: In general, there will be no solution if the inequality is strict. So, what you do depends on what you want. The $\epsilon$ trick will work, but if the constraint is active, then the solution will not necessarily be optimal for the original problem.

Answer (score 11):

In general strict inequalities are not treated in linear programming problems, since the solution is not guaranteed to exist on corner points.

Consider the $1$-variable LPP: $Max$ $x$ subject to $x<3$. Now there does not exist any value of $x$ for which maximum is achieved and which lies in the feasible region.

Comment: 1. Linear programs are not necessarily about optimization, they can also be about feasibility. 2. Replacing ‘$\max$’ with ‘$\sup$’ evades the technical issue you point out.

Comment: $x \le 3 - \epsilon$ ?