# Strict inequalities in an LP problem

Tags: inequality, linear-programming, operations-research, constraints

So I have to formulate an LP problem out of this scenario converting 3 variables into just 2 variables in order to use the graphical method. I guess I do that by using the demand constraint:

---

[image]

---

I think we should maximise

$$z = 280x_1 + 240x_2 + 320x_3$$

s.t.

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1000$$

$$400 \le x_1 \le 600$$

$$200 \color{red}{<} x_2 \color{red}{<} 300$$

$$100 \color{red}{<} x_3 \color{red}{<} 400$$

$$x_2 \le 1.5x_3$$

---

Is that right? If so, I thought to convert as follows:

---

$$\max \ z = 280(1000-x_2-x_3) + 240x_2 + 320x_3$$

s.t.

$$400 \le x_2 + x_3 \le 600$$

$$200 \color{red}{<} x_2 \color{red}{<} 300$$

$$100 \color{red}{<} x_3 \color{red}{<} 400$$

$$x_2 \le 1.5x_3$$

which produces this [feasible region](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=400%20%3C%3D%20x%20%2B%20y%20%3C%3D%20600,%20200%20%3C%20x%20%3C%20300,%20100%20%3C%20y%20%3C%20400,%20y%20%3D%3E%20(2%2F3)(x))

---

Is that right? If the inequalities are not strict then, I guess I just check the endpoints:

$$(200,400), (300,300), (300,200), (240,160), (200,200)$$

---

If they are strict, is the optimal solution $(240,160)$ ? It seems to give a $z$ value of $276,800$, but the points $(200,400), (300,300), (200,200)$ seem to give $z$ values higher than $276,800$ so perhaps points close to it may give $z$ values higher than $276,800$.

Checked WolframAlpha. [Yeah](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%20%3D%20280*(1000-x-y)%20%2B%20240*x%20%2B320*y,%20x%3D300,%20y%3D299.9). So technically there is no optimal solution?

---

Related question: [Strict inequalities in LP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173171/strict-inequalities-in-lp) . I don't think using $\epsilon$, as suggested there, is needed as not all the inequalities in this problem are strict.

---

From Chapter 2 [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ABIU1apSS8r3CbA&id=5EA51B764D593198%212679&cid=5EA51B764D593198).

Comment: I would interpret e.g. "between 200 and 300 pounds" as $200\leqslant x\leqslant 300$ unless specifically told otherwise...

Comment: @Math1000 So why isn't the ground beef stated in a similar way?